# Detecting loss of connection between server and client

Tags: java, php

How will the server know of client connection loss? does this trigger an event? is this possible to store code (server side) so that it can execute before the connection loss happen?

This connection loss can happen if:

- being idle for too long.
- client side terminated.

etc.

This i am asking in particular to Jsp and php.

Comment: In general? In a specific language? A specific type of server and connection? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the protocol you're talking about, but a "connection" is typically established through a three-way handshake, which causes both parties to simply agree that they're "connected" now. This means both parties remember in a table that there's an open connection to IP *a.b.c.d* on port *x* and what context this "connection" is associated with. All incoming data from that "connection" is then passed to the associated context.

That's all there is to it, there's no real "physical" connection; it's just an agreed upon state between two parties.

Depending on the protocol, a connection can be formally terminated with an appropriate packet. One party sends this packet to the other, telling it that the "connection" is terminated; both parties remove the table entries and that's that.

If the connection is interrupted without this packet being sent, neither party will know about it. Only the next time one party tries to send data to the other will this problem become apparent.

Depending on the protocol a connection may automatically be considered stale and terminated if no data was received for a certain amount of time. In this case, a dead connection will be noticed sooner, but requires a constant back and forth of some sort between both parties.

So in short: yes, there is a server event that can be triggered, but it is not guaranteed to be triggered.

Comment: if i am using php as server language can i catch that event ? or nature of server varies on the processes such as this one?

Comment: What kind of connection are you creating to a PHP server? 99% of PHP scripts answer HTTP requests, which are very short lived connections to begin with.

Comment: its session based. what i want to achieve is , to detect such event (if exists) that get triggers before the client get terminated. lets say i want to destroy the session on client side termination.

Comment: Are you talking about a standard website with sessions? Then there is no long running "connection". A connection only exists while the page is being *loaded*. There is no active connection while the page just sits there doing nothing in the browser!

Answer (score 2):

When you close a socket, the socket on the other end is notified. However, if the connection is lost ungracefully (e.g. a network cable is unplugged, or a computer loses power), then you probably will not find out.

To deal with this, you can send periodic messages just to check the connection. If the send fails, then the connection has been interrupted. Make sure you set up your sockets to only wait for a reasonable amount of time, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a typical client server architecture, server shouldn't bother about the connection to the client. Only client should bother about connection to server. Client should take measures to avoid the connection being dropped like periodically sending a keep alive message or similar to avoid timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Why does server need to bother about connection loss/termination.

Server job is to serve the request which comes from the client. That's it. If client doesn't receive the data it expected from Server then it can take appropriate action. If connection gets disconnected when server is doing some processing for giving data to client; then also server can't do much as http request is initiated by client.

So client can make a new request if for some reason it didn't get response.